How to measure the width and angle of two intersecting ropes using OpenCV?
The first picture below is the original image, showing a net. The ropes in the net are of two types: thick and thin. It is necessary to distinguish which are thick ropes and which are thin ropes through OpenCV, and measure their angles respectively.

import cv2
import numpy as np

def measure_rope_width(image):
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Grayscale Image', gray)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imshow('Binary Image', thresh)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    widths = []
    for contour in contours:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
        width = max(rect[1])
        widths.append(width)
    threshold = 10
    
    thick_ropes = [width for width in widths if width > threshold]  
    thin_ropes = [width for width in widths if width <= threshold]

    
    for contour in contours:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    return image, thick_ropes, thin_ropes


if __name__ == "__main__":
    image = cv2.imread('.\pics\webFebric.png')  
    image, thick_ropes, thin_ropes = measure_rope_width(image)
    cv2.imshow('Image with Rectangles', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("thick ropes width：", thick_ropes)
    print("thin ropes width：", thin_ropes)

I detected the minimum bounding rectangle of the contour, but this method doesn't enable me to measure the width of the net ropes, but rather the width of the grid gaps. I would be extremely grateful if there could be a stable and reliable way to measure the widths of the two types of net ropes.

What I sincerely hope is this: I wonder if OpenCV could identify the area of the net ropes, as shown in the red and green rectangular boxes in the following figure. In this way, the width of the ropes could be obtained by measuring the width of the rectangular boxes. I would be most grateful if you could assist me with this.


looks familiar. what did you improve over your previous, deleted question?

I wouldn't do it like this. Detect the main direction of the ropes (you could use FFT to detect frequencies and directions) and cast a line of sample points in this direction. (you could binarize the image first) This sample point will give you a plot where the value goes high when crossing a rope and low when sampling the background. Measure the width of the high values (how many of them before going down. Cast more parallel lines and take the average width (discarting lines that fall on the parallel ropes)

@ChristophRackwitz I have added code samples, detailed descriptions of the problems I encountered, and what I expect it to be like. The previous issue was closed. After I updated it, no one reviewed it. So I had to close the previous one and open a new one.
